# find class in tr jquery for dynamically added row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find the class which is used in tr. These tr are added dynamically. I am using the following code to achieve this, but it is not working as expected. Can anyone please tell why it is not working?

```
if (!($("tr:has(td.comboselected)").length > 0)) {
        alert('if');
        $(this).addClass("comboselected");
    } else {
        alert('else');
        $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Selectors don't care whether the elements are static or dynamic, they just operate on the current DOM.

Comment: above if condition is present in the method`$("#deviceInterfacetbl").on("click", "tr", function(event) {...}`. this is tr.

Answer (score 1):

hey i have made changes in ur code

check it

```
$("#deviceInterfacetbl").on("click", "tr", function (event) {                    
                var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
                if (!checkbox.prop('checked')) {
                    $(this).addClass("comboselected");
                    var id = checkbox.val(); $('#policyMaptbl').empty();
                    $('#classMaptbl').empty();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). To find the `tds` with class `comboselected` in `tr`.

```
if ($("tr td.comboselected").length > 0) {
    alert('if');
    $(this).addClass("comboselected");
} else {
    alert('else');
    $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
}
```

Comment: It is always returning false. i added the not to the if condition.

Comment: Can you share with us the html you have?

Comment: `$("#deviceInterfacetbl").on("click", "tr", function(event) {
  
 var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
 var tr = $(this).find("tr");
 
 if (!($("tr td.comboselected").length > 0)) {
     alert('if');
     $(this).addClass("comboselected");
 } else {
     alert('else');
     $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
 }
 
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});`

Comment: This is javascript, I want the generated html

Comment: Can you tell what to check in the html, because it was huge and included many css classes and jstl code.

Comment: I think we have correct script and it should turn true when any of row in page has td with class comboselected, If you are tring to apply this on particular block then you need to see on what event you have this code and what html we have

Comment: Yes the class will have for other rows in table.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
if ($("tr").find("td.comboselected").length) {
    alert('if');
    $(this).addClass("comboselected");
} else {
    alert('else');
    $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!($("tr td").hasClass("comboselected")).length > 0) {
        alert('if');
        $(this).addClass("comboselected");
    } else {
        alert('else');
        $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
    }
```

this will be helpfull for u

Comment: in this code it will find 'tr' tag and after that 'td' tag and after that it will find the class 'comboselected' as in jquery there is an inbuilt function .hasClass which will find the 'td' tag with the particular class.

Comment: edit your answer to add the explanation, rather than just comment; also, your answer seems backwards - it appears to be adding the class if the tag already has the class.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

For `class` comboselected on `td`

```
    if($("tr td.comboselected").length){
        $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("comboselected");
    }
```

For `class` comboselected on `tr`

```
    if($("tr.comboselected").length){
        $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("comboselected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply jquery each loop in all the tr of that table look like below :

**way 1 : if you assign unique Id of each tr when they created dynamically.**

```
  $("#yourTableId tr").each(function (index) {
   // index is the current row index.
   // find the id of current tr
   var id = this.id;
   var currentClass = $("#"+id).attr("class");     
   // currentClass is the class you need to find.....
  });
```

**way 2 : if you have not assign any id to dynamically created tr's**

```
  $("#yourTableId tr").each(function (index) {
   // index is the current row index.
   var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");     
   // currentClass is the class you need to find.....
  });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            if (!($("tr td").hasClass("comboselected"))) {
                $("tr td").addClass("comboselected");
            } else {
                alert('else');
                $("tr td").removeClass("comboselected");
            }
        });
```

exactly u want
this is the code

Comment: My function is below. I have tr inside that i have check box, i am using the 'on' method on jquery to update the tr, if we click on tr it will work fine, but if we click on check box, then two events will fire due to that, it is not working. I tried stop propagation and return false, to fire one event. But it is not working.

Comment: `$("#deviceInterfacetbl").on("click change", "tr", function(event) {
  
 var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
 var tr = $(this).find("tr");
 
 if (!checkbox.is(":checked")) {
  checkbox.prop('checked', true);
   $(this).addClass("comboselected");
  
  var id = checkbox.val();
  $('#policyMaptbl').empty();
   $('#classMaptbl').empty();
    } 
 
 } else {
   checkbox.prop('checked', false);
 
  $(this).removeClass("comboselected");
 }
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
 event.stopPropagation();
 return false;
});`